# php function to show time in digital clock format

Tags: php

I have created a php function to return time in digital clock format. My function is

```
function get_hh_mm_ii($unsorted_time) {
    //return $unsorted_time;
    if ($unsorted_time == '00:00') {
        return 'x';
    } elseif ($unsorted_time != '00:00') {

        $time = explode(":", $unsorted_time);
        $hh   = $time[0];
        $mm   = $time[1];

        //var_dump($hh/12); exit();

        if (($hh / 12) == 0) {
            $ii = 'am';

            return $hh . ':' . $mm . ' ' . $ii;

        } elseif (($hh / 12) == 1) {
            $ii = 'pm';
            $hh = $hh % 12;
            if ($hh == 0) {
                $hh == 12;
            }
            return $hh . ':' . $mm . ' ' . $ii;
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to pass value (02:03) or any other it always returns NULL. I checked its value using var_dump.

Comment: Do some debugging then. At what point does it go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
function get_hh_mm_ii($unsorted_time) {
    //return $unsorted_time;
    if ($unsorted_time == '00:00') {
        return 'x';
    } elseif ($unsorted_time != '00:00') {

        $time = explode(":", $unsorted_time);
        $hh   = $time[0];
        $mm   = $time[1];

        //var_dump($hh/12); exit();

        if ($hh < 12) {
            $ii = 'am';

            return $hh . ':' . $mm . ' ' . $ii;

        } else {
            $ii = 'pm';
            $hh = $hh - 12;
            if ($hh == 0) {
                $hh == 12;
            }
            return $hh . ':' . $mm . ' ' . $ii;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that 13 and anything else, except 12 divided by 12 is not one.

Comment: `($hh / 12) == 0)` statement shows that if variable/12 is 0 i.e anything below 12 is gives 0(divisor) in this check. and thing greater than or equal to 12 gives 1(divisor). Am I right with the logic that I implemented? though my code was not correct.

Comment: @RahulSingh php > var_dump(07 / 12);
float(0.58333333333333)
php > var_dump((07 / 12) == 0);
bool(false)

Answer (score 1):

I would just do:

```
function get_hh_mm_ii($unsorted_time) {
  return date('g:i a', strtotime($unsorted_time));
}
```

Comment: I can't tell if that's a question or a statement, but yes, `:` separated times work well for strtotime. [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) -- Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, but using `strtotime` and `date` should in combination should be all you need.

```
<?php

function get_hh_mm_ii($unsorted_time) {
        return date("G\:H A", strtotime($unsorted_time));
}


print get_hh_mm_ii("9.21 pm") . PHP_EOL;
print get_hh_mm_ii("9:30 AM") . PHP_EOL;
print get_hh_mm_ii("02:03") . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

Outputs:

```
$ php timetest.php 
21:21 PM
9:09 AM
2:02 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function startClock() {
    let today = new Date();
    let h = today.getHours();
    let m = today.getMinutes();
    let s = today.getSeconds();
    var d = today.getDay();
    var day = today.getDay();
    var dayarr = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat"];
    day = dayarr[day];
    let ampm = h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    h = h % 12;
    h = h ? h : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;
    h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h;
    s = s < 10 ? '0' + s : s;
    document.getElementById('ets-clock').innerHTML =
        day + " " + h + ":" + m + " " + ampm;
    let t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
<body onload="startClock()">
<div id="ets-clock" class="ets-clock ets-time" ></div>
</body>
```

Comment: While it is true that good written code could be readable by itself; you should avoid answering questions without adding a line or two at least explaining what you have done

Comment: Thank you i will update this soon and remember this things next time